# qt connect вызов функции не принадлежащей классу

Tags: c++, qt

Есть такой вот не очень хороший код:

```
int func (string a, string b)
{
    if (a.size()>b.size())
        return 1;
    else
        return 2;
}

void MainWindow::MenuN_1()
{
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
widget->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 250, 250));
QFormLayout *form = new QFormLayout(widget);
QLineEdit *le_number1 = new QLineEdit;
QLineEdit *le_number2 = new QLineEdit;
QPushButton *pb_check = new QPushButton("Сравнить");
QLabel *l_answer = new QLabel();

form->setWidget(0, QFormLayout::FieldRole, le_number1);
form->setWidget(1, QFormLayout::FieldRole, le_number2);
form->setWidget(2, QFormLayout::FieldRole, pb_check);
form->setWidget(3, QFormLayout::FieldRole, l_answer);

setCentralWidget(widget);
int n;
QString s1 = le_number1->text();
QString s2 = le_number2->text();
string number_1 = s1.toUtf8().constData(),
        number_2 = s2.toUtf8().constData();

connect(pb_check, SIGNAL (clicked()), this, SLOT (func(number_1,number_2)));

}
```

ошибка: No such slot MainWindow::func()

не знаю как исправить коннект, что бы при нажатии на кнопку выполнялась func, а в лейбл выводился результат этой функции

Comment: Так у вас func (string a, string b) это не слот, а обычная функция. Читаем тут https://evileg.com/ru/post/87/

Comment: func(number_1,number_2)) тут будет ошибка, т.к. le_number1->text() и le_number2->text() возвращают QString а не string

Answer (score 2):

Используйте лямда-функцию:

```
auto l = [this, number_1, number_2]() {
  int result = func(number_1, number_2);
  l_answer.setText(QString::number(result));
}
connect(pb_check, &QPushButton::clicked, l);
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте так.

```
connect(pb_check, &QPushButton::clicked, this, [this]()
{
func(number_1,number_2);
});
```

Предварительно в pro файле добавьте

```
CONFIG += c++11
```